Built-In Potential (Forward vs Thermal Equilibruim)
According to my book the built-in potential $V_{bi}$ for a PN junction under thermal equiliubrium is:
$$V_{bi}= \frac{KT}{q}In(\frac{n_{no}p_{po}}{{n_{i}}^2})$$
where $n_{no}$ and $p_{po}$ are the majority carrier electrons in the n side and majority carrier holes in the p side repsectively.
Here is the confusing part. My professor claims the following is true in forward bias:
$$V_{bi}- V_{F}= \frac{KT}{q}In(\frac{n_{no}p_{po}}{{n_{i}}^2})$$
Where $V_{F}$ is the forward applied bias. So in this case if I substitue $V_{bi}$ from the first equation the expression becomes zero for $V_{F}$ even though it is a parameter I control. So what is $V_{bi}$ ?
is it $$V_{bi}= \frac{KT}{q}In(\frac{n_{no}p_{po}}{{n_{i}}^2}) + V_{F}$$
or :
$$V_{bi}= \frac{KT}{q}In(\frac{n_{no}p_{po}}{{n_{i}}^2})$$

The built-in voltage $V_{bi}$, given by your first equation for a non-degenerately doped pn-junction, is usually defined for zero applied voltage, i.e., in thermal equilibrium. When you apply a forward bias $V_{F}$ to the pn-junction, the internal voltage drop over the space charge region is simply reduced by  $V_{F}$ and becomes  $V_{bi}- V_{F}$. But this internal voltage drop in non-equilibrium is usually not called a built-in voltage.
